# How to receive "Build queued" TFS notification/alert?

Tags: tfs, notifications

I want to try making a Slack bot for our team to show when a TFS build is queued. There are "Alerts" in TFS settings, which allow sending SOAP alert to a URL, but the only "build" events available are Build Completes/Fails/Partially Succeeds... basically when the build is done with one result or another. **But there's nothing to alert when the build starts/is queued.**

Yet, I've seen utilities that claim to show desktop popups when the build starts (and other build events). I assume this means there some way to get those notifications...

How can I monitor, or receive notifications from TFS when a build is queued? Tnx!

Comment: Which one are you using, the old XAML or new vNext?

Comment: it's **XAML** definition

Comment: It's unclear if you're asking for a tool that you want to use in order to receive such notifications, or if you are asking for a methodology to detect the events in order to write your own code to do this. If you are looking for a tool, then this is off-topic (requests for off-site resources are off-topic). If you're writing your own code and want to figure out how to do it, then this could be on-topic. Please clarify your question, so we know what you're really asking for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no build-in alert notification could send E-Mail when the build queued/started.

You can use the notification web services in TFS to built an app that will receive the web service notifications, and then do what ever you want; e.g. request the full build status, build start time, queued build info.

Detail step of how to please refer this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/narend/2006/07/26/faq-on-vsts-subscriptions-and-common-problems/).

Besides, you could also refer some 3-rd party source code for how to query the build status and use Notifications and alert system. Both for XAML and vNext.

- [TFS Build Notifications](https://github.com/mattwendels/tfs-build-notifications)
- [AnyStatus Plugins](https://github.com/AnyStatus/Plugins)

Comment: thanks. I'll accept the answer, it lead me to a solution. Basically, for start of a build, it seems, I need to keep polling API. Along the way I also learned that TFS version we use is 2013, which doesn't officially support REST API, which explains why I couldn't get it to work before posting here. But unofficially its available in it's early version. So, I figured out how to get the info I need and will try to build my bot. Thanks!